# Creating a static library project in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, static-libraries

How can i create a static library project in objective-c in xcode 3.2 for MAC OS X.

Comment: I want to create a static library written in objective-c. I have xcode 3.2 installed on MAC OS 10.6.8. And I am getting option only for creating dylib project through cocoa library.

Answer (score 0):

There is one fine tutorial for creating static library in objective .[here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)

You can create static library by following this tutorial.

Comment: Actually i want to create a static library for MAC OS, not for iOS. Will this iOS static lib project will work on MAC OS or it will only work on iPhone. I am totally confused, because there is no option to create any static lib project for MAC OS, The option contains only dymic lib creation.

Comment: sorry for this . But there is a option in Xcode to create a static library for mac .under mac osx static library and framework.

Comment: Sorry but I am using Xcode 3.2 and here under MAC OS-> Framework & Libraries -> I have options Which are- a) Cocoa Framework b) Cocoa Library c) BSD C Library and d) STL C++ Library. And all the projects are for creating dynamic library not a static one.